# How to initialize char**?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, char

Here is my piece of code:

```
char** filename;
*(filename) = "initialize";
printf("filename = %s",*(filename));
```

I got this error when I tried to run it:

```
Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'filename' is being used without being initialized.
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allocate room for filename using new or malloc. As it is, filename is just a pointer to a random area of memory you have not requested...

```
  filename = new char*;
```

Comment: @muntoo: No it isn't. The diagnostic message in the question indicates that filename is an uninitialized pointer. It is a pointer to char*, so filename = new char* is correct to make filename now be a pointer to an uninitialized pointer to char. Now, whether a double-pointer is actually needed is a separate topic.

Comment: Yes, I believe that the record will show that muntoo is incorrect on this one. It's OK - we all get a little overzealous sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

```
char *a  =  "abcdefg";
char **fileName = &a;
```

Answer (score 4):

C way:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * filename = (char*) malloc( 100 ); // reserve 100 bytes in memory
strcpy(filename,"initialize");           // copy "initialize" into the memory
printf("filename = %s",filename);        // print out
free(filename);                          // free memory
filename = 0;                            // invalid pointers value is NULL
```

C++ way:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

string filename("initialize");           // create string object
cout << "filename = " << filename;       // write out to stanard out
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char** filename = new char*;   
*(filename) = "initialize";    
printf("filename = %s",*(filename));
```

But why do you need that stuff?

Comment: Care to explain, @Muntoo? It's correct insofar as `filename` needs to have a non-null value holding the address of a `char*`. It's only incorrect in that `"initialize"` is an array that decays into a `char const*`, not a `char*`, so the type of `filename` was wrong from the start. Can't blame Ajay (or Thomas, or Joel) for that.

Answer (score 0):

@Naszta's answer is the one you should listen to. <s>But to correct all these other wrong answers on `new`:</s>

```
size_t len = strlen("initialize") + 1;
char* sz = new char [len];
strncpy(sz, "initialize", strlen("initialize"));
```

---

The *real* C++ way of doing it is better, of course.

```
string filename = "initialize";
cout << "filename = " << filename;
```

Answer (score 0):

For initializing `char **variable` you can also use the following way.

```
    //define length
    int length = 1;
    std::string init_str = "your_string";
    //inititlize char **var length
    char **my_var = static_cast<char **>(calloc(length, sizeof(char *)));
    my_var[0] = static_cast<char *>(calloc(init_str.size() + 1, sizeof(char)));
    //copy string value in char **my_var
    strcpy(argv[0], api_flag.c_str());
```

This way you can initialize for multiple values and assign values for length  (N)

Answer (score -1):

You haven't allocated the char* that you're trying to assign to:

```
char** filename = new char*;
*filename = "initialize";
```

Comment: Again, no it isn't, unless you want to pick on the fact that *filename isn't a pointer to const, in which case I'd agree with you.